# Cannot access local admin console of GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We are developing a web application on GAE for golang. Our program passed compiling and we can access contents of the application on a local machine.
But we cannot access local admin console and get an error as following.
My machine is Mac OSX 10.8 and GAE/G version is 1.7.0.

Anybody have idea?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 701, in **call**
>       handler.get(*groups)
>     File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/admin/**init**.py", line 1372, in get
>       self.generate('datastore.html', values)
>     File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/admin/**init**.py", line 238, in generate
>       'xsrf_token': get_xsrf_token(),
>     File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/admin/**init**.py", line 114, in get_xsrf_token
>       for i in range(6)]
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/random.py", line 191, in randrange
>   ValueError: empty range for randrange() (2147483648,-2147483649, -4294967297)

Comment: That's weird. I check the offensive line in the sdk and looks different from what is reported by the error. Can you post the lines 113 and 114 of file /usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/admin/init.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encountered this issue with OSX 10.8 + Python 2.5.6 + GAE 1.7.0

I made the changes as per below and it has helped me:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7885

Comment: The cause of my issue is same with yours.

I modified 
/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/admin/__init__.py:113

from:

`randints = ['%08x' % (random.randrange(-2**31, 2**31-1) & (2**32-1))`

to:

`randints = ['%08x' % (random.randrange(-2L**31, 2L**31-1) & (2L**32-1))`